# Position all elements relative to left edge of container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a better handle on CSS positioning by using only basic positioning properties. The goal is to get an HTML5 `input` and it's associated `label` to line up horizontally, one pair on each row, with the `label` on the left and `input` on the right. Essentially there will appear to be two columns, one for `labels` and the other for `inputs`.

I also want each column to be left-justified, which is where I'm currently stuck.

Using the CSS below I can get the two-column look I want, however none of the `input` elements are justified correctly.

If I set the position of the `input` elements to `absolut`, however (the thinking that adjusting the `left` property will align each element the same pixel length from the left containing edge), each element justifies properly, however all on the same row.

Any hints as to how to accomplish the two-column/left-justified layout w/o using tables or grid-column?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjwy3Lov/

**CSS**

```
/*Styles for basic form label and input elements*/

.basicForm{
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.basicForm label{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin:inherit; 
}

.basicForm input{
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    float:left;
    margin: inherit;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Form Validation Demo</title>
    <link href="form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML 5 Input Types and Form Validation</h1>
    <form class="basicForm">
        <label for="UserName">User Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" required="required">

        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="Password" required="required" />

        <label for="UserEmail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="UserEmail">

        <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="PhoneNumber">

        <label for="Website">Homepage:</label>
        <input type="url" id="Website">

        <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Quantity" min="1" max="10" step="1" pattern="/\d/">

        <label for="StartDate">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="StartDate" min="2000-01-02" max="2016-01-01">

        <label for="FavColor">Favorite Color:</label>
        <input type="color" id="FavColor">

        <label for="CurrentMonth">Current Month:</label>
        <input type="month" id="CurrentMonth">

        <label for="CurrentWeek">Current Week:</label>
        <input type="week" id="CurrentWeek">

        <label for="CurrentTime">Current Time:</label>
        <input type="time" id="CurrentTime">

        <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because as per your CSS all `input` elements are 150px to the left of the corresponding `label` but those are not the same width, so your `input`s are not aligned.

You need to make all labels the same width:

```
.basicForm label{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    min-width:150px;
}

.basicForm input{
    float:left;
}
```

Instead of `min-width` you could also use `width`, whichever you prefer.

If you insist on using absolute positioning, you could wrap each label/input pair in a div so you don't need to position each element individually, check this example:

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
  height:2em;
}
.input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.input-group input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <label>Label 1</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label>longer Label</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <label>short</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there any way to accomplish this using `absolute` positioning?